# How do I debug JSPs

Tags: debugging, jsp, netbeans6.8, weblogic9.x

How can I debug JSPs in my JSF1.6 application running on Weblogic 9 application server.
Right now I am using NEtBEans editor to debug my Java classses and that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Use Netbeans 7 and it allow debug the JSP files, obviously no html lines.

Comment: How do you put breakppoints for JSps in Netbeans ? I am unable to place breakpoints in JSps

Comment: Just like any java file, but some times i need to re-compile the files in debug mode. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/819/examplecg.png/